# SwiftUI lock DatePicker if not default

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am wondering if it is possible to lock the DatePicker if a date other than the default date was selected?

I am using trying to set up basic user profile page in my settings area so that users who are under 18 years old are not shown podcasts that are rated M.

Any assistance with this would be grateful.

settingsViewer.swift

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct SettingsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var userSettings = UserSettings()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Your Profile")) {
                    
                    TextField("Your Name", text: $userSettings.username)
                    
                    DatePicker(LocalizedStringKey("Date"),selection: $userSettings.dateofbirth,in: ...Date(),
                               displayedComponents: .date)
                    
                    Picker(selection: $userSettings.age, label: Text("Age Range")) {
                        ForEach(userSettings.ages, id: \.self) { agerange in
                            Text(agerange)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Picker(selection: $userSettings.gender, label: Text("Gender")) {
                        ForEach(userSettings.genders, id: \.self) { gender in
                            Text(gender)
                        }
                    }
                    Text("The above is optional, but by filling out this section you will save time when entering competitions as this information will autofill. This data will not be transferred to DRN1 servers unless entering a competition.").font(.system(size: 12))
                }
                Section(header: Text("Station")) {
                    Picker(selection: $userSettings.favStation, label: Text("Favourite Station")) {
                        ForEach(userSettings.favStations, id: \.self) { favStation in
                            Text(favStation)
                        }
                    }
                    Text("By selecting your favourite station, when the app launches it will automaticlly start playing the station you have selected above.\n\nNote: This wont come into effect until you restart the app.").font(.system(size: 12))
                }
                
                Section(header: Text("Legal")) {
                    List{
                        NavigationLink(destination: TermsOfServiceView()) {
                            Text("Terms of Service")
                        }
                        
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text ("Item 1 Destination")) {
                            Text("Privacy Policy")
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Settings", displayMode: .inline)
        }
        //.navigationBarTitle(Text("Settings"), displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```

UserSettings.swift

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var username: String {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(username, forKey: "username")
        }
    }
    
    @Published var dateofbirth: Date {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(dateofbirth, forKey: "dateofbirth")
        }
    }
    
    @Published var favStation: String {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(favStation, forKey: "favStation")
        }
    }
    
    public var favStations = ["DRN1", "DRN1 Hits", "DRN1 United", "DRN1 Life", "DRN1 Dance"]
    
    @Published var age: String {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(age, forKey: "age")
        }
    }
    
    public var ages = ["17 or Under", "18 - 24", "25 - 34", "45 - 55", "56 +", "NA"]
    
    @Published var gender: String {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(gender, forKey: "gender")
        }
    }
    
    public var genders = ["Male", "Female", "Intersex/unspecified", "NA"]
    
    init() {
        self.username = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "username") as? String ?? ""
        self.dateofbirth = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "dateofbirth") as? Date ?? Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)
        self.favStation = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "favStation") as? String ?? "DRN1"
        self.age = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "age") as? String ?? "NA"
        self.gender = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "gender") as? String ?? "NA"
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a if else if date == default date show picker else show Text

Comment: @loremipsum yes but I am trying to lock the DatePicker once set - and the issue is that as soon as you change the month or day it is locking it - when I do an if compare date with default date.

Comment: I get it. Maybe have a Bool that tells you it is the initial setup  that way the user can only change it once. Or have an initial setup view that has the picker and then only show the view that only displays the date

Comment: @loremipsum yep - I like that idea. I just tried  .onReceive(Just(userSettings.dateofbirth)) {
                                                print($0)
                                            } 

But because it instantly sends the date back to the userSettings I need away to do like a if 2min or longer inside the onReceive and then set a userSettings to lock I think that maybe the best way? Thoughts?

Comment: Have a save button don’t save the settings until the user does that initial save

Comment: @loremipsum interesting idea, but by default it will auto save. - But saying that I could check at the next start up of the app, and if the date of birth is different it locks it.